# Parse APEX RESTful WebService reference JSON response stored in CLOB001 column

Tags: json, web-services, rest, oracle-apex

I am trying to generate a report page in my APEX application, using the data obtained from a REST service response.

I added a new RESTful webservice reference and sepecified a JSON output.

Then I've generated a query/report page, but this is what's being currently displayed:

[image]

Instead I want the report to display the contents of data field on the JSON response (A single row with various columns and values)

Is there any straight forward way to show each response element and field on its row and column instead of a single column and row with the whole response, like there is with XML RESTful responses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider whether another output type may be more handy. If you're putting out JSON and expect to handle it in PLSQL, then you do need to realize that PLSQL does not handle that natively.

Want to handle the rest response as json in plsql? Then look into some PLSQL libraries/projects that may do this:

- http://reseau.erasme.org/pl-sql-library-for-JSON?lang=en
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/pljson/

Then print out the returned HTML through `HTP.P` calls. 
Though honestly, if you want to stick with plsql you would be much better off using XML as a return type, since you can then use all the xml goodies in the database. Though simply spitting out some html structure may not be quite too interesting (but I digress).

Or call the rest service through an ajax call from javascript, and handle the object there. After all, `JSON` is Javascript Object Notation and should be perfect for javascript, right? Then simply inject your html somewhere in the document. Ideally you would set up a region as a container for this.

Comment: That was pretty much my line of thinking and now I've modified the rest service to output XML instead (A one line modification, after all). I was just wondering, with JSON being so popular for rest services, how come there is no straight forward way to handle response parameters, as it is for XML? The examples I've found also use AJAX calls, but if I need server-server communication (I don't want the client to be able to see the details of this call or I'm calling an internal service) and modifying the REST service to output XML is not an option it would be nice to have that kind of feature...